# Obstacle insertion in map

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, costmap, obstacle-avoidance

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a sensor to detect obstacles that are not visible. I want my robot to avoid them because they are dangerous despite not being visible.

I have a path planning working with my laser sensor. So, I imagine that the best way of avoiding this potentially harmful points is by introducing them in the obstacle map.

Is it possible?
How can I do it and prevent the laser clearing them in the map?

Thank you

EDIT:

I am using navigation package with my TOF camera to implement an AMCL and a path planning. The problem I have is that I need to add invisible obstacles (they are recognised by a radio frequency system). My path planning is working properly right now, but I need to introduce more information in the map.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198553/obstacle-insertion-in-map/) by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 223 on 2014-11-28

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-11-28**:
What kind of sensor is it?

**Comment by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on 2014-12-01**:
I have explained it above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you checked out the [ROS Navigation](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation)?  It looks as if you can develop a [SLAM map](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Build%20a%20map%20with%20SLAM) using this set of packages.

---

Originally posted by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) with karma: 323 on 2014-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on 2014-12-02**:
I am using navigation package with my TOF to implement an AMCL and a path planning. The problem I have is that I need to add invisible obstacles (they are recognised by a radio frequency system). My path planning is working properly right now, but I need to introduce more information in the map.

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2014-12-02**:
I'm not sure how your radio frequency sensor works, but if it gives you the position of the obstacles that it senses, you should be able to publish that information to the appropriate topic.  As long as you have the right message format, you should be good.  I would examine other sensor nodes.